# Cakephp handle MySQL enum

Tags: php, cakephp

I got an enum datatype field in MySQL table named "privacy" = enum("Public","Private","Custom"). I want to show this field on my edit view like,

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->input(
              "privacy",array(
                   'label'=>'',
                   'type'=>'select'
              )
         );
  ?>
```

I tried [this](http://debuggable.com/posts/How_to_Fetch_the_ENUM_Options_of_a_Field_The_CakePHP_Enumerable_Behavior:4a977c9b-1bdc-44b4-b027-1a54cbdd56cb) link solution but found two major problems with it.

1.) I need to pass the available options to the view from controller and need to assign them to the field in view file.

2.) It pass array as Numeric index, so on form submit view will pass the value's index rather than it's value. So if I select privacy option as "Custom", view will pass as 2 which eventually not gonna saved in database, cause its enum and 2 is not a valid option.

I thought that cakePHP is smart enough to evaluate that the provided field is enum and it will fetch all the available options from database and handle that field on it's own.

Is there any option in cakephp which solves my issue or do I need to pass a hard coded associative array to my view?

Answer (score 1):

here is some code which is very useful to you to select gender as enum datatype

in view file

```
<?php
                echo $form->input('gender', array(
                        'type'=>'select',
                        'options'=>array("male" => "Male", "female" => "Female")
                    )
                );
```

and for controller you just have to initialize

```
$this->data['Profile']['gender'] = $sel_gender['Profile']['gender'];
```

let me know if i can help you more...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know how to create select box from array by passing array, but I am trying to create select box from enum datatype without passing array.

Comment: but as you ask above you also want to make edit time default selected by user above second code it useful to you

Comment: Though it is enum datatype I thought cakephp will handle available options and default selected value on its own. I thought cakephp will fetch the enum values and populate them in selectbox. If I need to pass a hard coded array, what's the meaning of defining datatype enum.

Comment: but i think it could be available with custom helper to add in your code. pls find that way it can be possible